# How to Instantiate GameObject from Interface list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interface, casting, typing

So, i have `List<ITower>`.

If I try to do:

```
var a = new List<ITower> {new DotBehaviour(), new RndBehaviour()};

foreach (var tower in a)
    Instantiate(tower);
```

I get:

> The type 'ITower' must be convertible to 'UnityEngine.Object' in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic method 'T UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate(T)'

So I would be happy if:

a)  you tell me how to do this OR

b) how to make return method in interface, that would return prefab associated with GameObject I want to instantiate.
(Idk how to do this because of strong typing of C#, but I don't want to use `dynamic`)

Comment: You could try to cast it to UnityEngine.Object and then all the method you want. Just make sure to check if the cast was successful.

Comment: There is no guarantee that an interface is implemented by a particular class, so you can't instantiate an interface. If you have a particular object you want to instantiate and keep reference to using your list of interfaces you should consider implementing a factory that instantiates the specific object you want, and passes your interface back.

Comment: Have you consider an abstract base class instead? Also (no DOTs expert) is it even allowed to create instances using `new` for behaviours? I know that for `MonoBehaviour` it's absolutely "forbidden" ^^

Comment: 1. Direct cast is impossible (method already tries to do so). 2. I asked how to do this in a). 3. It is just demonstrational list to not copypaste loads of code, so example may be dirty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a default interface method implemetation in the newest version of C#, but I don't know if unity implemented it yet. If they did you potentially could define a method in you interface and return the prefab you want to insantiate. Something like:

```
GameObject GetPrefab()
{
    return Resources.Load("Path/To/My/Prefab");
}
```

then you would call Instantiate(tower.GetPrefab()); instead of Instantiate(tower);.

If you Unity version does not have a support for default interface methods, then you would have to implement the GetPrfab method in relevant scripts

Comment: So, this is the correct answer for newer unity version. But I did all based on tutorials, that were recorded long time ago, so transfering all prefabs from other folders to resources would be problematic. I'll search for another answer for some time, and post smth if I'll solve this somehow else

Comment: This will work for any Unity version. The only difference is if you have a default interface implementation, then you can define this method only once, in the relevant interface. Otherwise you will have to define this method in each implementation of the interface. I wrote a blog about an alternative for the resources folder over here: https://www.anton.website/resource-manager-and-object-pooling/. Perhaps it will help